# very big mysql table slow

Tags: mysql

I have a very big table in Mariadb in MYISAM ENGINE

this is the table payments:

id;date;costumer_id;paid_value

--;----;----------;--------

I have 141918688 rows on it

I have two index, primary in id, index in date, index in costumer_id

If I want to query the last 5 payments ordered by date DESC

I have this

```
SELECT paid_value FROM payments WHERE costumer_id=12 ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT 5
```

but it takes 0.5 seconds, and use only one index(customer_id), not fecha index(date)

Why? how can I improve the query to use the two index and do the query in minus 0.0x? because this can be a problem in the future with a more big table

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Does adding "LIMIT 5" improve the performance?

Comment: no, it takes 0.05 seconds, its fast, but i think in the future it can go up to 1second or more

Answer (score 1):

With your current query you are essentially grabbing every payment related to `Customer 12`. Since you only want the last 5, you'll have to use [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) to limit the fetched rows to `5`:

```
SELECT paid_value FROM payments WHERE costumer_id = 12 LIMIT 5 ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: yes, but it takes the same 0.05 seconds to complete, and only uses "costumer_id" index, it ignore "date" index

Comment: Maybe it can be go long in the future with more rows to read?

Comment: What do you mean *it ignores 'date'* ?

Comment: ignores "date" index, I think maybe the query can use costumer_id and date at same time to improve the query, how can I force the query to do this?

Comment: It's using both the `id` and the `date`. It uses the `id` to handpick the relevant payments and `date` to sort the findings. Also, a query that runs in `50ms` in a table with so many rows sounds fine to me. I think you should not trouble yourself with assumptions like *"in the future it can go up to 1second or more"*. If a problem arises then, solve it at that time instead of trying to over-optimise everything now, because it may sometime in the future occur. It probably never will 

Comment: Besides, I don't think the query in my answer can be optimised any further. Perhaps you could use a date to narrow down the results to only the most recent before sorting, but that's assuming you know which date to use in advance.

Comment: if I use explain, mysql show it only use customer_id index, not date.

Comment: Have yoiu tried adding an index that is both customer_id and date? A composite index. Then if you select customer_id, date from .... order by. It should use the correct index.